# Need Suggestions! About crossTab

Tags: mysql, datagridview, playframework-2.0, pivot-table, crosstab

I want to transform my samples / analyzes into a crosstable or gridview or something looks like, so that users can enter results. Here is an example:

[image]

1. What's the best way to do firstly export data into a crosstab like this
2. How does something like pivot js table or crosstab gona return entered data to my java controller for inserting results to the right samples/analysis....

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest that your final question is back to front. You would normally go from data set, to json result, to gridview

Comment: Hi Strawberry, I work on play framework, i can export data as json to a crosstab, but what about returning dataentered to the controller ? I want to know 3 things :    1- what kind of tools can i use to display this form ? 2- how to send data to this tool ( ex json )   3- how to get structural dataentered ( samples/analysis/results ) to finally update database (in java controller)....

Comment: Recommend doing such in your application.